# Warning: Illegal string offset 6

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on creating a timetable but I have a couple of error:

`$query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '{$array['dj']}'");
$array2 = $db->assoc( $query2 );
$query3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE id = '{$array2['displaygroup']}'");
$array3 = $db->assoc( $query3 );`

But my website shows the problem:

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'dj' in C:\xampp\htdocs\content\tpl\styles\Habbo\rooster.php on line 111
Warning: Illegal string offset 'displaygroup' in C:\xampp\htdocs\content\tpl\styles\Habbo\rooster.php on line 114`

can anyone help ?? I do not work with mysql mysqli with something else

Comment: Those keys(or better said, columns) do not exist in the database.

Comment: your $array objects are not arrays but strings; it has nothing to do with an SQL error

Answer (score 0):

```
$array['dj']
```

you try to access the value at the key dj of the $array variable, but the key dj does not exist.

```
array2['displaygroup']
```

you try to access the value at the key displaygroup of the $array2 variable, but the key displaygroup does not exist.